# Intersection of circle with two line segments not detecting all intersection points

Tags: python, math, geometry, sympy, intersect

I am using SymPy's [geometry module](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/geometry/) to intersect line segments and circles. It seems only some intersection points are being counted, while many others are ignored.

Here is some test code for finding the intersection points:

```
from sympy.geometry import Point2D, Segment2D, Circle

# Point A, B and C
A = Point2D(1, 1)
B = Point2D(3, -1)
C = Point2D(-2, -2)

# Segment from A to B
f_0 = Segment2D(A, B)
# Segment from A to C
f_1 = Segment2D(A, C)
# Circle with center A and radius 0.8
c = Circle(A, .8)

i_0 = c.intersection(f_0)
i_1 = c.intersection(f_1)

print(i_0)
print(i_1)
```

This should work, and does catch all intersection-points when doing line-circle intersection or circle-circle intersection, but not segment-circle nor ray-circle intersection. Here is the output:

```
[]
[Point2D(217157287525381/500000000000000, 217157287525381/500000000000000)]
```

It's obviously not working as intended. I don't know what causes this, and I'd like to know how to fix it or find any alternatives (preferably still using SymPy).

[image: [geogebra depiction of geometry]]

Comment: This looks like an interesting problem--I wish I had time to work on it. You would make your question more attractive and better fit the rules of this site by making the code more **minimal**. Use just two points, one line segment, and one circle, and find where the code does not work as it should. Read and follow [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and you will get more, better answers. You should also make the code **complete** by including all the needed import statements.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion @RoryDaulton . I've simplified + completed the code down so only relevant information is left. Always nice to learn Stackoverflow etiquette.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I still do not know why my previous method did not work, but i know one that will. After messing around in Wolfram|Alpha i realized the coordinates of intersection where all irrational. Seeing the output of the program being a fraction, something was obviously wrong. It turns out that the radius of the circle, 0.8, caused all of the trouble.

Instead of giving a float as an argument, you need to sympify it first. It is important to remember two things:

1. The argument needs to be a string and not a float.
2. The 'rational' flag needs to be True.

With this in mind, the new code becomes:

```
from sympy import sympify
from sympy.geometry import Point2D, Segment2D, Circle

# Point A, B and C
A = Point2D(1, 1)
B = Point2D(3, -1)
C = Point2D(-2, -2)

# Segment from A to B
f_0 = Segment2D(A, B)
# Segment from A to C
f_1 = Segment2D(A, C)
# Circle with center A and radius 0.8
c = Circle(A, sympify('.8', rational=True))

i_0 = c.intersection(f_0)
i_1 = c.intersection(f_1)

print(i_0)
print(i_1)
```

The output then becomes:

```
[Point2D(2*sqrt(2)/5 + 1, -2*sqrt(2)/5 + 1)]
[Point2D(-2*sqrt(2)/5 + 1, -2*sqrt(2)/5 + 1)]
```

Comment: Yes, SymPy has a lot of trouble with equations that involve floating point numbers. I suggest  `Rational('.8')` as a shorter way of forming rationals like this (a shorter yet is `S(4)/5` where S is a built-in shortcut for "sympify").